# Can anybody tell me the schema markup for add-ons, workforce?

Tags: schema.org

I'm having difficulty sorting-out each element of my web-pages. I don't know in which category each element falls.

Plus, whenever I am able to categorize an element, I'm never able to find the right schema for it on the web.

Comment: 1) Do you mean Schema.org? 2) And how is JSONschema related here? Or do you mean JSON-LD? But that would just be a syntax to express Schema.org …

Comment: I am unable to categorize the elements on each page of my website. I don't know how to apply schema to my website. My website: www.wsoutsourcer.com, for example the home page starts with 4 slides, what code should be applied into the html file? As there is no property for slides within schema.org, this is very confusing.

Comment: See my answer on Webmasters SE about [how to find a suitable type](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92108/17633).

Answer (score 0):

The guide of Google **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** requires that the structured data represent the main content of the web page to which it refers.

So, if the main content of your web page represents a local business, then the structured data should represent this local business - it may be useful to use here the **[guide of Google for Local Business](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)**. If the main content is a person, then the structured data must represent the person using the type **[Person](https://schema.org/Person)**.

Here the key phrase is "***main content***". Do not be "***too diligent***" in creating structured data. Do not create structured data for each element of the webpage. Do not create too many separate types of structured data because they will compete and divide the juice among themselves. Most likely it will be ignored by Google and not available as rich results in the SERP, which means it will be a meaningless markup that only increases the volume of the webpage and lowers the download speed for mobile (search rank signal).

**[Google supports the following structured data formats](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#structured-data-format)**:

- **[JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/)** (Recommended)
- **[Microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/)**
- **[RDFa](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/)**

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. Can anybody quote a schema example for a about us page?

Comment: You probably inattentively read my post. Structured data markup MUST represent the main content of a web page that is referenced. Without main content, no templates can be offered for you. You have to do it yourself.